# SQL insert function crashed when no connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert

the insert function works fine when sql served is connected. However, as I testing abnormal environment, such as lose sql connection, the function would go crash.

Please advice what to do in order to prevent this happened.

```
    public static daily Insert(String time, int i, String production, String prodRep, String Tprod, String speed, String current)
    {
        String query = string.Format("INSERT INTO daily(time,station,production, ReplaceProduction, TotalProduction, speed, current) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')", time, i, production, prodRep, Tprod, speed, current);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConn);
        dbConn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        daily user = new daily(time, i, production, prodRep, Tprod, speed, current);
        dbConn.Close();
        return user;
    }
```

Add try-catch, red-underline note will appeared as the following.
[red underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPvmB.png)

Comment: Why not check for a working connection and act upon that?

Comment: The red-underline appears because your code doesn't return anything outside of the try-catch block.

Comment: Got it. The problem solved after adding return outside try-catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `try-catch` so it will not crash, when exceptions are handled accordingly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27209465)

Comment: @ikos23 Albeit not comprehensive, this answer is technically correct. On top of that it doesn't explicitly recommend swallowing exceptions, like the accepted answer does.